How can I add classmethod to the FastAPI object?
I am trying to add more functions to FastAPI's Request class, but can't seem to do so.
I have an example:
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

class MyPersonalRequest(Request):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

  @classmethod
  def human_readable_datetime(self):
      return "some nice date/time message"

@router.get('/info')
async def info(request: MyPersonalRequest):
    print(request.human_readable_datetime())

But i'm getting the error, that it does not recognize the new function:
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'human_readable_datetime'

When I print the object - I don't see my class also:
#print(request)
<starlette.requests.Request object at 0x1072eb0d0>

How can I overload the Request class then ?

One possible way is described in: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/custom-request-and-route/ - Another way is to not modify the request object, but instead have a separate dependency that provides the required data (which in turn depends on the request).

I followed the document, the above is the result, the error that I mentioned above is what I received ... what am I doing wrong compared to that example in the doc (lets say the class GzipRequest(Request) example? where it overload the body function, i want to add a new one, not to override an existing function of Request.

Ah, my bad - that won't change the Request object in your signature, that's correct. Then my second question is: what would a classmethod inside the Request object help with? Since it's a class method, it can't access any values from the request instance, so why wouldn't a regular dependency used with Depends work? (and if it needs information from the request, make the dependency depend on the request instead)

@MatsLindh i thought that by overloading the Request I will be able to get information stored inside (i.e: info from the user like IP etc ) i'm keeping the information in a specific structure where I need to run the same command all the time over and over. before the above example - i did used a regular function but I thought that overloading the Request is cleaner than functions hanging around everywhere...

But you're defining these as class methods, which won't have access to the instance information (i.e. what's specific for each request) in either case. Using a dependency makes it far clearer what the controller requires, instead of "hiding" it away inside the Request object and having to know what value to receive; think of a dependency here as "this is what I need to validate/get to execute my function" (for example a valid user, etc.) Exactly how to structure that is hard to say without knowing what your classmethods should do.

@MatsLindh well ... i thought about just helper functions w/o any arguments ... like one i mentioned above which probably doesn't make much sense, but also something like: user's base directory in my project which is a /{param1}/{param2}/{request.username}/ that construct the information inside the request differently, it's easier to be consistant across the project with request.user_base() vs import myutils; & myutils.user_base(request) ...

UserBaseDir = Annotated[str, Depends(resolved_user_path)], then async def foo_endpoint(user_base: UserBaseDir): in every endpoint where you need access to it.
